# Unresolved dependency Invite (Version 3.x required)

Tags: 7, upgrading

I have upgraded drupal , but when i am running update.php I am getting this error .
I have tried after disable invite but still no luck.

Unresolved dependency   Invite (Version 3.x required)
User Relationships Invites requires this module and version. Currently using Invite version 4.0-beta2

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i just found solution . I have have disabled User Relationships Invites using db from system table and it works .